# Turn based game, how do you decide the turn between player and computer

Tags: javascript

Trying to code a turn based battle mode for a game and i can not manage to get it to change turns between the player and the computer.

I'm using random number to set first turn but after that it wont change character

what i have tried so far is a while loops and if statements

I'm using the enchant.js framework but plain java-script would do if any one can help

this is my code:

```
var Battle = Class.create(Scene,{
initialize: function(){
    var battle = Game.instance;
    Scene.apply(this);
    console.log('Battle Screne');
 /*
 *  Background
 */
    var bg = new Sprite(320, 320);
        bg.image = game.assets['./assets/BS.png'];
        this.addChild(bg);

 /*
 *  Player Battle Sprite
 */
    BattleHero = Class.create(Sprite,{
        initialize:function(x,y){
        Sprite.call(this, 32,32);
        this.image = game.assets['./assets/SpriteSheet.png'];
        this.x =x;
        this.y =y;
        this.frame = [6];
        this.scaleX += 2;
        this.scaleY += 2;
        //battleScene.addChild(this);
    }});
    hero = new BattleHero(32*1,32*5);
    this.addChild(hero);
/*
 *  Enemy Battle Class
 */
    BattleNpc = Class.create(Sprite,{
        initialize:function(x,y){
        Sprite.call(this, 32,32);
        this.image = game.assets['./assets/SpriteSheet.png'];
        this.x =x;
        this.y =y;
        this.frame = [16];
        this.scaleX += 2;
        this.scaleY += 2;

    }}); 
    npc = new BattleNpc(32*8,32*5); 
    this.addChild(npc);

/*
*   Attack
*/      
    var turn = Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1);
    console.log('turn equals',turn);

    if(turn == 1){
        console.log('player Turn',turn);
        var attack = new Button("Attack");
            attack.x = 32;
            attack.y = 32*7.5;
            attack.addEventListener(Event.TOUCH_END, function(e) {
                console.log('attack pressed');
                hero.tl.moveTo(32*8, 32*5, 5);//.moveTo(32*1.5, 32*5, 5);
                    if(hero.intersect(npc)){
                        console.log('melee hit');
                        hero.tl.moveTo(32*1.5, 32*5, 5);
                        //game.popScene();
                        turn ++;
                        return move = false;
                        console.log('turn is now',turn);
                    }
            }); 
        this.addChild(attack);

//Item Button
    var item = new Button("Item");
        item.x = 32;
        item.y = 32*8.5;
        item.addEventListener(Event.TOUCH_START, function(e){   
            turn = turn++;
        });
            this.addChild(item);
//Run Button
    var run = new Button ("Run");
        run.x = 32*4;
        run.y = 32*8.5;
        run.addEventListener(Event.TOUCH_END, function(e) {
            game.popScene();
        });
        this.addChild(run);
    }

//Npc Attact
    else{   
    console.log('Enemy Turn',turn);
    npc.frame = [16];
    npc.tl.moveTo(32*1.5, 32*5, 5).moveTo(32*8, 32*5, 5);

        if(npc.within(hero,16)){
            console.log('melee hit');
            npc.x = 32*8;
            return move = true;
            turn= turn--;
        };
    }

}});
```

Comment: There's a lot of confusion in the code about what happens when... are you trying to create new buttons on every turn? For performance, you'd be better off creating all the buttons at the beginning, then just allowing the actions based on what turn it is...

Answer (score 0):

If you extract your code into separate functions, instead of doing everything in the `initialize()` function, you would be able to change turns at will.